# Better way to check if every value in a nested array is true or false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a nested array like this.

```
var arr = [[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false]]
```

I want to check if every value is false. I could think of one way of doing this.

```
let sum = 0;
arr.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.forEach((col, j) => {
      sum = sum +arr[i][j]    
    });
});
if(sum === 0){
    console.log("all values false")
}
```

This works. But I'm curious if there is a better way? to check if all values are true or false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take two nested [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because if you found one `true` value the iteration stops. Then take the negated value.

```js
var array = [[false, false, false, false], [false, false, false, false], [false, false, false, false], [false, false, false, false]],
    result = !array.some(a => a.some(Boolean));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I decided to use this solution. I don't need to check every value in my case. My bad, I should have mentioned in the description. Good one!

Answer (score 9):

You can use nested `every()`

```js
var arr = [[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false]]
const res = arr.every(x => x.every(a => a === false));
console.log(res)
```

To make the code a little more cleaner you can first `flat()` and then use `every()`

```js
var arr = [[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false]]
const res = arr.flat().every(x => x === false)
console.log(res)
```

I am considering you want to check of only `false`. If you want to check for all the falsy values(`null, undefined` etc). You can use `!` instead of comparison with `false`

```
const res = arr.every(x => x.every(a => !a));
```

Comment: beat by milliseconds, bravo

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```js
var arr = [[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false],[false,false,false,false]]

let result = arr.every(x => x.every(y => y === false));
console.log(result);
```